# how to select only month and year in @react-native-community/datetimepicker

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker

I am using `@react-native-community/datetimepicker` in my project to select date from calendar.

```
import RNDateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';

const getDatePicker = (
  display:
    | 'default'
    | 'compact'
    | 'inline'
    | 'spinner'
    | 'clock'
    | 'calendar' = 'default',
) => {
  return (
    <RNDateTimePicker
      testID="dateTimePicker"
      value={changedDate ? new Date(changedDate) : currentDate.toDate()}
      mode="date"
      themeVariant="light"
      display={display}
      is24Hour={true}
      textColor={
        CommonFunctions.isAndroid() ? Colors.textOnPrimary : Colors.textDark
      }
      onChange={(e: any, value: Moment.MomentInput) => {
        if (value) {
          const curDate = Moment(value)
            .utcOffset(0, false)
            .format('YYYY-MM-DD');
          setShow(false);
          setChangedDate(curDate);
        } else {
          setShow(false);
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

This is working fine. But my problem is that I only want to select month and year. I don't want to select date.

Comment: A separate custom picker must be configured.

Comment: @pratteekk Have you got any option? I'm finding solution for same

Comment: according to this it isn't possible https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/issues/23#issuecomment-580501882